# VBA Microsoft Project Professional 2016: How do I write Actual Hours with specific data

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am simply trying to add Actual Work Hours data per day for each Task and Resource?

How can I write a hours on actual work column (For example  X task R Resource on 07.02.21 he work 4 hours  and on 07.03.21 he work 3 hours how can I add these data using vba macros to MS Project)

Example:

```
Dim tsk as Task
Dim finder as string
dim names as string

for each tsk in activeproject.tasks

if instr(tsk.text1, "TASK CODE" )> 0 then
finder= tsk.text1
if instr(tsk.ResourceNames, "Name")>0 then

' Implement the actual data codes here 

endif
endif

next tsk
```

To sum up

How can I add the data on Actualk Work to spesific people in spesific task.

Answer (score 0):

The method needed is [TimeScaleData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.timescaledata). Here's an example of how to use it to set actual work hours for 7/2 and 7/3, at the resource assignment level:

```
Sub SetActualHours()

Dim tsk As Task
Dim names As String

For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks

    If InStr(tsk.Text1, "TASK CODE") > 0 Then
        Dim asn As Assignment
        For Each asn In tsk.Assignments
            If asn.Resource.Name = "Name" Then
                
                Dim tsv As TimeScaleValues
                Set tsv = asn.TimeScaleData(StartDate:=#7/2/2021#, EndDate:=#7/4/2021# _
                    , Type:=pjAssignmentTimescaledActualWork, TimeScaleUnit:=pjTimescaleDays)
                tsv(1).Value = 4 * 60
                tsv(2).Value = 3 * 60
                
            End If
        Next asn
    End If

Next tsk

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your code,
If there are more than 2 people in 1 task in MS project

Set tsv = tsk.TimeScaleData(StartDate:=#7/2/2021#, EndDate:=#7/4/2021# _
                 , Type:=pjTaskTimescaledActualWork, TimeScaleUnit:=pjTimescaleDays)

This code is defined directly to general tasks actualwork. How can I add their actual work separately to the people in this task?

Comment: @PleaseHelp See updated code. The TimeScaleData method also works at the resource assignment level.